# Using breakpoints in CoffeeScript Express.js app

Tags: node.js, express, debugging, coffeescript, webstorm

I'm attempting to configure WebStorm to respond to breakpoints in an Express.js app, written in CoffeeScript. I am able to get the program to pause at breakpoints when express is initially starting up, but the breakpoints don't work when sending requests to the app from a browser.

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "./node_modules/coffee-script/bin/coffee app.coffee",
    "compile-coffeescript": "coffee --map -c .",
    ...
}
...
```

**debug configuration**
[image]

[image]

In production, the application is booted with `nodemon app.coffee`. From what I understand, WebStorm requires CoffeeScript to be transpiled to JS, with source maps included, for breakpoints to work.

So for development, I've configured WebStorm to execute the `compile-coffeescript` command (from package.json) to generate source maps, then boot the app through a generated `app.js` file instead of the original `app.coffee` file.

Does this process look correct for debugging a CoffeeScript Express app?

#### Other notes

- Tested with Google Chrome on Mac.
- JetBrains browser plugin is installed and works with other (non-coffeescript) projects.

Comment: if you are pre-compiling .coffee using npm script and passing compiled code to Node.js, what's the reason for using `-r coffeescript/register`? it's supposed to be used for on-the-fly compilation.

Comment: Debugging pre-compiled .coffee server works for me (`"coffee-script": "^1.12.7"`, `"coffee --map -c ."` used for compiling). I'd suggest creating a support ticket - must be a configuration issue